# How to return javascript success data to jQuery property

Tags: javascript

The below function is working fine and I am getting response from ajax get function, the data is comming in 'res.data.value' in JSON format, Now i want to pass this data to events property of full calender in array format. If i am passing static values to events property it is working fine. Please help me as I am unable to pass 'res.data.value' value dynamically.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    var completedInterviews = function() {
        var requestParams = [];
        requestParams = {
                "url": dashboardServiceUrl + '/dashboard/widget/completedinterview',
                "requestType": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                }
        }

        var res = makeRequest(requestParams);
        res
        .done(function(res) { 
           return  [res.data.value];
        })
        .fail(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

    };    

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
      },
      defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
      editable: true,
      navLinks: true, 
      eventLimit: true, 
      events: completedInterviews(),  // I want [res.data.value] value here.
      loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
      }
    });

});

</script>
```

/*
 * function to make API call using AJAX, Deffered and Promise 
 */

```
function makeRequest(requestParams) {
    var headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken
    };
    // concating extra headers
    headers = jsonConcat(headers, requestParams.headers);

    // checking return content type
    var dataType = "json";
    if(headers.Accept == "application/xml") {
        dataType = "xml";
    }

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var response = $.ajax({
        url: requestParams.url,
        type: requestParams.requestType,
        dataType: dataType,
        data: JSON.stringify(requestParams.params), 
        headers: headers,
        success: function(res) {
            if(res.error != null) {
                deferred.reject(res.error);
                if(res.error=="Invalid Token") {
                    //window.location.href = "";
                }
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(res);
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: try `JSON.parse(res.data.value)`

Comment: Thanks for  reply,    .done(function(res) { 
                                  return  JSON.parse(res.data.value);
                               }) is not working

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 0):

Use calendar in then statement.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    var completedInterviews = function() {
        var requestParams = [];
        requestParams = {
                "url": dashboardServiceUrl + '/dashboard/widget/completedinterview',
                "requestType": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                }
        }

        res = makeRequest(requestParams);

        //RETURN RES
        return res;

    };

    //WRAP CALENDAR WITH THEN
    completedInterviews().then(function(data){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
          },
          defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
          editable: true,
          navLinks: true, 
          eventLimit: true, 
          events: data,  // ADD DATA.
      loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
      }
    });
    });



});

</script>
```

Comment: I edit my code, still didn't get success , if i console.log(completedInterviews()) , it gives me undefined

Comment: see my edited code

Comment: @wasimbeg edited answer. can you try again with that solition?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, when I do console.log(data) , it gives me res value i.e. {state: ƒ, always: ƒ, catch: ƒ, pipe: ƒ, then: ƒ, …}  rather than  [res.data.value];

Comment: Can you delete `done` and `fail` from `res.` Return res directly.